# Cannot connect to Samba shares after reinstall

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, samba

I have a home file server on which I have recently reinstalled the OS. I replaced Ubuntu Server 10.04.2 32-bit with 10.04.3 64-bit due to hardware upgrades. I've copied my previous Samba configuration over, recreated the share user, and made sure the permissions for the shared directories, on another disk, were still intact. I have an XP and a Win7 machine. Both can see the file server, but neither can access the shares. If I go to `\\Server` on a Windows machine, it prompts for a user/pass and appears to accept the connection. If I go to `\\Server\Share` next, it asks for a user/pass again, and will not authenticate.

No network settings have changed on the Windows machines. Is there some other configuration I might be missing for the server? What else could be wrong?

**Troubleshooting:** I found the logs, as suggested. smbd and nmbd are both running. In the logs for the windows machines, I get a lot of lines like this when trying to connect.

```
[2011/11/07 07:23:53,  1] smbd/service.c:676(make_connection_snum)
  create_connection_server_info failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
```

This is clearly the problem, but I don't know why it's happening. The user and pass I'm using are good, and it was working before the upgrade. I did find this in log.winbindd-idmap:

```
[2011/11/07 07:14:12,  1] winbindd/idmap.c:321(idmap_init_domain)
  idmap initialization returned NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
[2011/11/07 07:23:40,  0] winbindd/idmap.c:201(smb_register_idmap_alloc)
  idmap_alloc module tdb already registered!
[2011/11/07 07:23:40,  0] winbindd/idmap.c:149(smb_register_idmap)
  Idmap module passdb already registered!
[2011/11/07 07:23:40,  0] winbindd/idmap.c:149(smb_register_idmap)
  Idmap module nss already registered!
[2011/11/07 07:23:40,  1] winbindd/idmap_tdb.c:214(idmap_tdb_load_ranges)
  idmap uid missing
[2011/11/07 07:23:40,  0] winbindd/idmap_tdb.c:287(idmap_tdb_open_db)
  Upgrade of IDMAP_VERSION from -1 to 2 is not possible with incomplete configur
ation
[2011/11/07 07:23:40,  1] winbindd/idmap.c:321(idmap_init_domain)
  idmap initialization returned NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
```

log.smbd

```
[2011/11/06 20:01:29,  0] smbd/server.c:1069(main)
  smbd version 3.4.7 started.
  Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2009
[2011/11/06 20:01:29,  0] printing/print_cups.c:103(cups_connect)
  Unable to connect to CUPS server localhost:631 - Connection refused
[2011/11/06 20:01:29,  0] printing/print_cups.c:103(cups_connect)
  Unable to connect to CUPS server localhost:631 - Connection refused
[2011/11/06 20:01:29,  0] smbd/server.c:1115(main)
  standard input is not a socket, assuming -D option
```

log.nmbd

```
[2011/11/06 13:40:55,  0] nmbd/nmbd.c:854(main)
  nmbd version 3.4.7 started.
  Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2009
```

smb.conf, most of which is stock

```
[global]
   workgroup = MyGroup   # edited
   server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
   dns proxy = no
   use sendfile = yes   # edited
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   syslog = 0
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   security = user   # edited
   encrypt passwords = true
   passdb backend = tdbsam
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user
   guest account = myshareuser   # edited
   usershare allow guests = yes

[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700

[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = no

# added
[share]
path = /mnt/storage/share
force user = myshareuser
force group = myshareuser
read only = No
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
guest only = No
guest ok = No

[backup]
path = /mnt/storage/backup
force user = myshareuser
force group = myshareuser
read only = No
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
guest only = No
guest ok = No
```

Comment: You need to troubleshoot. Is `smbd` running? Is `nmbd` running? What's in the log files?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thanks for the hint, I've added some details above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a corrupt passdb.tdb file.  If you remove it and restart Samba can you add users?

Comment: I found more detail on this problem here: http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=54952

Answer (score 2):

Try following:

```
sudo smbpasswd -L -a username   (set a password)
sudo smbpasswd -L -e username   (enable user)
```

You can also add the content of /etc/samba/smb.conf with the problem details. Besides, you can give a try with webmin. for details check the below link:

[webmin](http://www.webmin.com/)

Comment: The first line fails with "Unable to modify TDB passwd: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL!", and the second fails with "Failed to find user myshareuser in passdb backend." (which I assume is because the first failed).

Comment: Try below solution...don't hesitate to get back if you find any confusion :)

Comment: Can you try with adding a new user like - `sudo adduser testuser` (set your password & necessary info). then `sudo smbpasswd -a testuser` (do not set any password here, just keep pressing enter), this should give an output like the `Added user testuser`

Comment: It wouldn't add with a new user. Turns out deleting the /var/lib/samba/passdb.tdb file allowed me to run these commands successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. If you have not got the solution yet, please try below:

```
sudo system-config-samba
```

It will give you a gui like:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

check the 'preferences' box (Samba settings & samba users).
You can add your share from File--> add share

**Besides,if still the problem exists then you can also try to edit /etc/samba/smb.conf file  like below, i guess which may solve your problem :**

```
usershare allow guests = yes
security = user
guest ok = yes
guest account = exampleuser 
username map = /etc/samba/smbusers


# added
[share]
path = /mnt/storage/share
valid users = myshareuser
read only = No
guest ok = yes
browseable = yes

[backup]
path = /mnt/storage/backup
valid users = myshareuser
read only = No
guest ok = yes
browseable = yes
```

Then execute the below commands:

```
sudo chmdo 777 /mnt/storage/share /mnt/storage/backup
sudo stop smbd
sudo start smbd
```

Now check whether the share works :D

**For interactive user authetication following may work**

Add an user in the system & give the password

> sudo adduser testsamba

Add the user to Samba & ***keep the password blank when asked here again***

> ```
> sudo smbpasswd -a testsamba
> ```

Map the windows user

> ```
> sudo vi /etc/samba/smbusers
> ```

the file should contain like below:

> ```
> testsamba = windowsuserSample
> ```

Do the necessary configuration with the GUI as before

> ```
> sudo system-config-samba
> ```

restart samba service

> ```
> sudo service smbd restart
> ```

Comment: Adding 'valid users = myshareuser' and 'guest ok = yes' does allow the share to be accessed, but with out a password. I was hoping to require password access to at least one of them.

Comment: Have u checked the "system-config-samba"??? there is an option for your desired user mapping. You can map a windows user through that.

Comment: Plz check the added part & don't hesitate to get back soon :D

Comment: I don't actually have any GUI for this install, but those instructions could be helpful to others. Thanks for trying to help me step through this.

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: Yes. If I could accept two answers, I'd accept your first answer as well. David's answer was the key piece of the puzzle, however.

Answer (score 0):

@Jay Sheridan, I have tried the following & it should work. It's just a summery version of the last reply. You can check it.

1. Install samba server, In  the terminal type the command:

> ```
> sudo apt-get install samba smbfs
> ```

1. Make  a  configuration for share:

> `sudo vi /etc/samba/smb.conf`

edit like this :

> `[global]`
>
> `security = USER`
>   `hosts allow =`
>
> `[homes]`
>
> `comment = Home Directories`
>
> `browseable = no`
>
> `writable = yes`
>
> `[share]`
>
> `comment = Unixmen File Server`
>
> `path = /share/`
>
> `force user = samba`
>
> `force group = samba`
>
> `read only = No`
>
> `hosts allow =`

**add a user (For example: unixmenuser to  the  system, in the terminal type the command :**

> `root@unixmen-desktop:~# adduser unixmenuser`
>
> `sudo smbpasswd  -a   unixmenuser`

the output of the second command should be like below

---

> `Output`
>
> > `New SMB password:`
> >
> > `Retype new SMB password:`
> >
> > `Added user unixmenuser.`